# Allowframebreaks not working on beamer references

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

Slides are not breaking on beamer references.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Berlin}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{Author1,
author = {Authorr1},
journal = {Journall - 1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA},
pages = {1--2},
publisher = {Publisherr - 1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA},
title = {{titlee - 1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}},
volume = {1},
year = {2017}
}

@article{Author2,
author = {Authorr2},
journal = {Journall - 2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA},
pages = {1--2},
publisher = {Publisherr - 2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA},
title = {{titlee - 2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}},
volume = {1},
year = {2017}
}

@article{Author3,
author = {Authorr3},
journal = {Journall - 3AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA},
pages = {1--2},
publisher = {Publisherr - 3AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA},
title = {{titlee - 3AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}},
volume = {1},
year = {2017}
}

@article{Author4,
author = {Authorr4},
journal = {Journall - 4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA},
pages = {1--2},
publisher = {Publisherr - 4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA},
title = {{titlee - 4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}},
volume = {1},
year = {2017}
}

@article{Author5,
author = {Authorr5},
journal = {Journall - 5AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA},
pages = {1--2},
publisher = {Publisherr - 5AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA},
title = {{titlee - 5AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}},
volume = {1},
year = {2017}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{References}
\begin{frame}
\cite{Author1}

\cite{Author2}

\cite{Author3}

\cite{Author4}

\cite{Author5}
\end{frame}

\section{References}

\begin{frame}[label=ncurrent,allowframebreaks]{\secname}%WORKAROUND REMOVES HERE
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}%WORKAROUND ALSO REMOVES HERE

\end{document}
```

[image]

The workaround I got is to remove `\begin{frame}` `\end{frame}` that surrounds `\printbibliography`, but then I lose the section title.

Comment: Can you live without `label=ncurrent`?